# React Testing onClick Console.log

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I am very lost.  I need to confirm that the onClick is being fired when the button is clicked.  It logs "Click" in the console but I think I need to make sure the "click" logs in the console in order to assert in the test that it is functional.  I am sure the expect is wrong but can't seem to find the right answer through my normal means.  Any help would be much appreciated.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Button onClick={() => console.log('Click')} />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Button.js

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Button(props) {
    return <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>Click me!</button>;
}
```

Button.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

import Button from "./button";

describe("<Button />", () => {
  it("Should call props.onClick when the button is clicked", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Button onClick={() => console.log("Click")} />);
    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(console.log).expect.stringContaining("Click");
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure if you can actually test on the console.log functionallity. The way to go here would be to create a mock function, pass it as the `onClick` function and then make sure it has been called 1 time after you `.simulate` the click.

Check the example here https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html

Comment: Thanks!  That did it!